# Extract specific text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract the text of the div on hover but so far I getting the text of all the divs.

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='a'>a</div>
    <div class='a'>b</div>
    <div class='a'>c</div>
    <div class='a'>d</div>
    <div class='a'>e</div>
</div>
```

I tried using the following command :

```
$('.a').on('hover').text();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you want `$('.a').hover(function() { alert($(this).text(); });`

Comment: @Tushar `$.fn.hover` function is shorthand for `mouseenter/mouseout`, not what OP is expecting here (firing event on 'mouseover' only i guess)

Answer (score 2):

To get the first div only, target `a:first` then get the text of that element using `this`

```js
$('.a').on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='a'>a</div>
    <div class='a'>b</div>
    <div class='a'>c</div>
    <div class='a'>d</div>
    <div class='a'>e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad, i want the text of the hovered div only

Comment: If you don't just want the first, which is what you explicitly asked for in your question, just remove `:first`

Comment: still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
$('.a:first').on('mouseenter', function() {
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='a'>a</div>
    <div class='a'>b</div>
    <div class='a'>c</div>
    <div class='a'>d</div>
    <div class='a'>e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the text of the hovered div.

```js
$('.a').on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='a'>a</div>
    <div class='a'>b</div>
    <div class='a'>c</div>
    <div class='a'>d</div>
    <div class='a'>e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this returns the text in all the divs

Comment: Yes, it will return the text of the current hovered div. Do you want something else?

Comment: this returns, a b c d e

Comment: I don't know how you getting that output, it's showing me the text of div which is I am hovering.